# Cross Compile Ubuntu eclipse to arm beaglebone

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, cross-compiling

I have a process I have been using for a number of years to cross compile applications for the beaglebone black.  the download I last was using was

gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linix

I have several programs that worked, but I recently got more creative so I decided to upgrade to a new toolchain, so I downloaded and installed:

gcc-linaro-5.2-2015.08-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf

Now even the simplest file will not compile.

The compiler claimed that it could not find features.h.

I thought that that was probably a file that came from the beaglebone.  Sure enough, so I brought it in from the beaglebone and now it complains that it can't find bits/predefs.h.  That file is also on the beaglebone but I seriously doubt that this is what I am supposed to do.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a 64 bit OS.

Edit more detail:

if my program does nothing but

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

the output from make is 
/usr/local/arm/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/5.2.1/features.h:323:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory

if I comment out the #include

the output is:

**arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L/usr/local/lib/arm -L/usr/local/arm/lib -o "FTDTest"  ./src/FTDTest.o

/usr/local/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/local/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/local/arm/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.1/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lm**

---

**Solution:**
The problem was the sysroot from the toolchain was not pointing to the correct directory.  Since I can't change the sysroot without rebuilding the toolchain I moved the directories for the sysroot to the directory the sysroot was pointing to and it works like a charm.  It's not the best solution but it will let me get by.